# "Prepared statement contains too many placeholders" on update query using WHERE NOT IN

Tags: mysql

I have an update query which looks something like this:

```
UPDATE table SET xyz = 'abc', updated_at = '2021-09-27 23:00:00' WHERE external_id NOT IN (1, 2, 3...);
```

The trouble I seem to be having is that there are too many values in the WHERE clause (approx 50000).

It results in me getting the following error:

**Prepared statement contains too many placeholders**

If it wasn't for the fact it's deleting based on a value not being in a list, I'd chunk the values into smaller sizes.

Any ideas how I can get around this?

Comment: Is that the real query you are sending? There are no placeholders.

Comment: Probably instead of `IN`, try with a join

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a temporary table containing all the IDs you want to restrict. Add an index to the column in the table. Then use

```
UPDATE table 
SET xyz = 'abc', updated_at = '2021-09-27 23:00:00' 
WHERE external_id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM temporary_table);
```